# Misnamed Groovy Artifact groovy-all-1.0-jsr

Tags: maven, ant, groovy, activemq-classic, ivy

I'm attempting to install activemq-client 5.8.0, which requires groovy-all-1.0-jsr-03.  However, the ivy.xml for groovy-all-1.0-jsr-03 has the following publication, which seems to be incorrect:

```
    <publications>
            <artifact name="groovy-all-1.0-jsr" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
    </publications>
```

which causes ivy to try to download

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy-all/1.0-jsr-03/groovy-all-1.0-jsr-1.0-jsr-03.jar

which obviously does not exist, and should be

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/groovy/groovy-all/1.0-jsr-03/groovy-all-1.0-jsr-03.jar

which is valid.  So theoretically, the ivy for groovy-all-1.0-jsr-03 should be:

```
    <publications>
            <artifact name="groovy-all" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
    </publications>
```

My question is if there's a way using ivy rules to rename around this problem so that it properly resolves and is downloaded.  I've used rules in my ivy settings before, but only for redirecting to another organization, module, or revision.  I haven't found a way to redirect artifact names for publication references.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I can't [see where activemq-client 5.8.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.activemq%7Cactivemq-client%7C5.8.0%7Cjar) requires Groovy from 7 years ago...

Comment: Apparently activemq-client 5.8.0 relies on [activemq-openwire-generator 5.8.0](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.8.0/activemq-openwire-generator/dependencies.html), which requires gram 1.1, which requires [groovy-all 1.0-jsr-03](http://repo1.maven.org/maven/groovy/poms/gram-1.1.pom)

Comment: activemq-openwire-generator is an optional dependency of activemq-client.